# If statement is not accepting my input

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Goal: When the user enters in a color not in the list, it should default to gray. If the user chooses a color in the list that color should be used.

What is actually happening: Color is always defaulting to gray.

Plain text example 1: Choose a color: yellow, green, red, purple or gray.
User: Blue.
Output: Color is gray.

Plain text example 2: Choose a color: yellow, green, red, purple or gray.
User: Green.
Output: Color is Green.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="Choose yellow, green, red, purple or gray")]
[string]$color_select

)

$colors_list = "yellow", "green", "red", "purple", "gray", "random"

if ($color_select -notcontains $colors_list) {

$color_select = "gray"

}


Write-host "The color is: $color_select"
```

Comment: should be: `if ($colors_list -notcontains $color_select)`

Comment: @supertoy: Yes, you are asking if the list is in the selected colour.

Comment: if ($color_select -notin $colors_list) ..

Comment: Dang, too easy. Thanks y'all, it's working now.

Answer (score 5):

Doing this is easier, in my opinion:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="Choose yellow, green, red, purple or gray")]
    [ValidateSet('yellow','green','red','purple',"gray", "random")]
    [string]$color_select="gray"
)
```

It doesn't make sense to set the parameter as mandatory, if you plan to omit it.